# Insert an array of cards inside a mySQL table, no error to console

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I hope I'm not asking a question that has already been asked. I have tried looking around for some good steps on how to do what I am trying and this is my best result from those searches.

This takes some explanation of what I have in my head.

So, I am making a card game for my discord server. I am using "card-deck" ([https://www.npmjs.com/package/card-deck]) to handle the cards. I already have many of the cards saved to this same database in a different table (so I am not using a card constructor). This card game has multiple piles the cards would be moved to and from after originating from the main deck; Hand, discard pile, main deck, energy pile, activated cards etc.... My logic was to have the main deck be loaded, then allow players to pull cards from the deck and into their hands, energy pile, discard pile, etc... via commands.

I have a database created with a different column for each of the piles for each player (deckAcards, deckBcards, handA, handB, etc...) I have a test deck saved with a small amount of cards in it. I can retrieve that deck (saved in a different table in the Database) without issue. However, when I try to save said array into the correct column of the table, I am stuck. I'm not even certain this is how to setup this sort of project.

Here is my code where I attempt to insert the array of cards retrieved from one table of the database into the table set up with all the info for that game. The resulting array of cards that were retrieved from the database is saved as "arr_cardname" at the very top of the code here.

```
var loadeddeck = arr_cardname;

        if (message.author.id == playerAid) {

          message.channel.fetchMessages().then(messages => {
          const botMessages = messages.filter(message => message.author.bot);
          var brawlID = botMessages.last().content.slice(-8)
          var brawlname = `brawlID${brawlID}`

            var maindeckA = new Deck(loadeddeck)

            var playerAdeck = JSON.stringify(arr_cardname)

            console.log(playerAdeck)

            sql = `INSERT INTO ${brawlname} (deckAname, deckAcards) VALUES ("${deckname}", "${playerAdeck}")`;
            con.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err; 
                else {
                    message.channel.send(`${deckname} and play areas loaded for Player A!`)
            }
            })
        })

          //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          } else if (message.author.id == playerBid) {
         //Make a copy of the above block for Player B
```

When I run the above code, I get no error printed to the console and nothing is input into the table I specified.

My other concern is that having the deck in this table won't allow me to use the deck objects made from "card-deck". Mainly, I just want to be able to store, access, modify the layout of cards and move them from the different piles as the game is played. (Drawing a card moves the top cards in deck to hand, discarding a card moves a card from the hand to the discard pile, etc) I was originally trying a JSON file, but I've read it can easily get messed up or corrupted if accessed and modified often, so I didn't want to risk that and I went with a database instead.

Any advice, corrections or suggestions for how I should go about making this work would be wonderful and appreciated as I have been spinning my wheels for several days now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the error correctly:

```
...
sql = `INSERT INTO ${brawlname} (deckAname, deckAcards) VALUES ("${deckname}", "${playerAdeck}")`;
con.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    else {
        con.query(sql)
        message.channel.send(`${deckname} and play areas loaded for Player A!`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Edited my code above. I am still seeing no error when running it though. It runs up until the sql = area, then seems to ignore the rest.

Comment: why are you trying to run the same sql query twice ?

Comment: I'm... not sure. XDMust be left over from some attempt to fix it. Still no error for some reason when I remove it though. I'm confused as to why this isn't even running now. Thanks for the help so far.